How to avoid alerting to create incident from same type of error log pattern?
I’m working on a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project where we have a custom log-based metric alert set up for VM instance errors (VM_instance_application_error). Currently, this alert is generating incidents every 5-10 minutes, leading to alert fatigue and significant disruptions for my team.
What I’ve Tried:
Adjusting the notification rate limits.
Exploring options for grouping incidents in GCP but couldn’t find the console page in GCP.
Expectation/Question:
Is there a way to configure/ Group GCP alerts using GCP console to trigger less frequently or to consolidate multiple incidents into a single alert? Any guidance on best practices or specific configuration suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
While exploring options for grouping incidents, I couldn’t find the specific console page in GCP. If anyone has experience with this, could you provide a step-by-step guide or point me to the right documentation?
I have attached a image below which will show the timestamps of incidents created from the alert. i.e currently it is creating almost 15 to 20 incidents per day and i want to club it together to notify as a single incident or consolidated one.
timestamps of the incidents created from the alert
Thank you for your help!
